# boost::hana: Why can't I filter a set?

Tags: c++, template-meta-programming, boost-hana

I'm using boost::hana, and I'd like to filter a boost::hana::set.

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>
#include <type_traits>

int main(){
    using namespace boost::hana;
    auto a = make_set(1,'a',3);
    auto b = remove_if(a, [](const auto& x){return bool_c<std::is_same_v<decltype(x), char>>;});
    // expects b to be make_set(1, 3);
}
```

This results in a static_assert failure. It tells me:

```
static assertion failed: hana::remove_if(xs, predicate) requires 'xs' to be a MonadPlus

         static_assert(hana::MonadPlus<M>::value,
```

Why does this fail? Why can't a set be a MonadPlus, even though the empty set and the concatenation operation is defined?

Comment: Probably because a set is not a sequence, as `set` s _must_ contain unique elements. If you want something more concrete, then you can find the definition of a `hana::MonadPlus` in `hana` s code, and just follow it back to see what pre requisites `hana::set` is missing.

Comment: This is a perfectly legit and answerable question. Why was it downvoted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter a list you should use `hana::tuple`. The idea of a Set is more general than MonadPlus or even Monad. Your assertion that `hana::set` has implementations for `hana::concat` or `hana::empty` is incorrect, and besides it also requires the data structure to be a Monad.

Base on your example, perhaps what you are looking for is [`hana::difference`](http://boostorg.github.io/hana/structboost_1_1hana_1_1map.html#a718ddfe86437adbbca1e1a5db651d139), but `hana::set` itself is pretty useless for this. It's operations require `hana::Comparable` and don't play well with run-time state.

If you want to "filter" sets by their type and maintain run-time values, I suggest using `hana::map` which also supports set operations. You can make its keys the `hana::type` of its value. This still requires uniqueness by its type.

Here is an example:

```
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;

constexpr auto typed_set = [](auto&& ...x) {
  return hana::make_map(
    hana::make_pair(hana::typeid_(x), std::forward<decltype(x)>(x))...
  );
};

int main() {
  auto a = typed_set(1, 'a', 3.0f);
  auto b = typed_set('c');
  auto c = hana::difference(a, b);

  BOOST_HANA_RUNTIME_ASSERT(c == typed_set(1, 3.0f));
}
```